# Getting the class of an n dimensional array of an runtime supplied class name

Tags: java, arrays, class, reflection

Given a fully qualified class name, and a number of dimensions, i would like to get the Class name for this class. I believe i can do this like such

```
public Class<?> getArrayClass(String className, int dimensions) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> elementType = Class.forName(className);
    return Array.newInstance(elementType, new int[dimensions]).getClass();
}
```

However this requires me to create an unneeded instance of the class. Is there a way to do this without creating the instance?

It does not appear that Class.forName("[[[[Ljava/lang/String;") (or a algorithmically generated version) works correctly in all instances from various blog posts i've seen. (bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6434149)

Comment: shouldn't it be [[[[Ljava.lang.String; instead of [[[[Ljava/lang/String;?

Comment: well, either way various posts say thats not valid in all contexts.

Comment: You are not creating an instance of the class, but a zero length array. Why do you think, the algorithmic construction of the `"[[[[[[Lclassnamehere;"` string is cheaper or in any way better than constructing a zero length array? By the way, the linked bug refers to `ClassLoader.loadClass(…)` not `Class.forName(…)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `[[[Ljava.lang.String;` notation is the standard way of representing array class names.

The XMLEncoder and XMLDecoder use standard Java functionality to write and read arrays:

```
String[][][] foo = new String[3][4][5];
foo[0][0][0] = "a";
foo[2][3][4] = "z";
XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(System.out);
encoder.writeObject(foo);
encoder.flush();
encoder.close();
```

yields the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<java version="1.6.0_22" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder"> 
 <array class="[[Ljava.lang.String;" length="3"> 
  <void index="0"> 
   <array class="[Ljava.lang.String;" length="4"> 
    <void index="0"> 
     <array class="java.lang.String" length="5"> 
      <void index="0"> 
        <string>a</string> 
        ...
```

I currently don't see any problem in using Class.forName() with a self-built class name (e.g. prepending the `[L`, since it's also used by the Java standard classes in the same way.

```
Class arrayClass = Class.forName("[L" + "java.lang.String" + ";");
```

And as the [JavaDoc for Class.forName](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) describes, the class is loaded but not initialized, and you also don't need to create an instance for it.

> If `name` denotes an
>   array class, the component type of
>   the array class is loaded but not
>   initialized.

Your last remark about various blog posts where this would not work would be interesting to investigate.

Answer (score -1):

The only way that i could think of is pass the class instead of string.

The point is that i am assuming here is, the calling class, may be for most of the cases be knowing the class.

```
public V[] getArrayClass(Class<V> c, int dimensions) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return (V[])Array.newInstance(c, new int[dimensions]).getClass();
    /* The type cast is required. Since Array.newInstance 
   is not genrically parameterized. */
}
```

Comment: I don't have the class. I am using asm to read the class signature, and trying to create the class from the signature.