# find class of array (String[].class --> String.class)

Tags: java, reflection

I've got an array of any class and I need to get that class at runntime.

I'm thinking of something like that:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[10];
Class<?> clazz = stringArray.getClass();
if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    System.out.println("Won't happen");
}
```

The class of the array is not known at compile time.

I've found something simular but the other way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13392304/2355146) (String.class --> String[].class)

Comment: I should have known this was a dupe. Heck, I'm not sure I haven't answered it before. (To self:) *Tsk.*

Comment: You still can use `array instanceof String[]` if that’s all you want to check. Otherwise, `array.getClass().getComponentType()` *should* be easy to find in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)…

Comment: I dont have an Instance - i have just a class. But `getComponentType()` does the job.