# Other ways to obtain `int[].class`?

Tags: java, matlab, reflection, primitive-types

I would like to obtain `int[].class` from Matlab. Unfortunately, Matlab does not allow this syntax. Simultaneously, I allows to call any Java functions or access static members as is.

For example, I can't call

```
int.class
```

but can

```
java.lang.Integer.TYPE
```

Is it possible to find `int[].class` somewhere in JDK API in the same way?

Comment: what do you expect from int[].class ?

Comment: How about `(new int[]{}).getClass()` ?

Comment: Does it support arrays at all?

Comment: Or ... `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Integer.TYPE, 0).getClass()`

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/13392160/2891664 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/4901128/2891664.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele it does, bot not with Java syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I tried this in a jshell:

```
int[].class.getName()
```

And that yielded:

```
[I
```

And tried to reverse it:

```
Class.forName("[I")
```

And that seemed to parse it: `class [I`

So you could try `Class.forName("[I")`. And that seems to work just fine:

```
Class.forName("[I").isArray() // outputs true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org) package in order to achieve your goal. Signally, [ClassUtils.getClass](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#getClass-java.lang.String-) is what you are looking for:

```
>> org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils.getClass('int[]')

 ans = 
       class [I
```

For the sake of analyzing things deeply:

```
>> ans.get()

              Annotation: 0
             Annotations: [0×1 java.lang.annotation.Annotation[]]
          AnonymousClass: 0
                   Array: 1
           CanonicalName: 'int[]'
                   Class: [1×1 java.lang.Class]
             ClassLoader: []
                 Classes: [0×1 java.lang.Class[]]
           ComponentType: [1×1 java.lang.Class]
            Constructors: [0×1 java.lang.reflect.Constructor[]]
     DeclaredAnnotations: [0×1 java.lang.annotation.Annotation[]]
         DeclaredClasses: [0×1 java.lang.Class[]]
    DeclaredConstructors: [0×1 java.lang.reflect.Constructor[]]
          DeclaredFields: [0×1 java.lang.reflect.Field[]]
         DeclaredMethods: [0×1 java.lang.reflect.Method[]]
          DeclaringClass: []
          EnclosingClass: []
    EnclosingConstructor: []
         EnclosingMethod: []
                    Enum: 0
           EnumConstants: []
                  Fields: [0×1 java.lang.reflect.Field[]]
       GenericInterfaces: [2×1 java.lang.Class[]]
       GenericSuperclass: [1×1 java.lang.Class]
               Interface: 0
              Interfaces: [2×1 java.lang.Class[]]
              LocalClass: 0
             MemberClass: 0
                 Methods: [9×1 java.lang.reflect.Method[]]
               Modifiers: 1041
                    Name: '[I'
                 Package: []
               Primitive: 0
        ProtectionDomain: [1×1 java.security.ProtectionDomain]
                 Signers: []
              SimpleName: 'int[]'
              Superclass: [1×1 java.lang.Class]
               Synthetic: 0
          TypeParameters: [0×1 java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable[]]
```